# Array manipulation in java script based on different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Hi everyone I'm trying to achieve following task.
I had list of 1.participants in a array with id, user name in objects, its length can be a Even/Odd. (lets say 9), 2.based on the room count (lets say 4), I have to push users to breakout room new array based on the room count.
Until what I tried is in below snack. it would be great appreciable which could help me to achieve this.
I'm sure that what I had tried until is not correct.

```js
const users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        user: 'User 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        user: 'User 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        user: 'User 3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        user: 'User 4'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        user: 'User 5'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        user: 'User 6'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        user: 'User 7'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        user: 'User 8'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        user: 'User 9'
    }
];

const usersCount = users.length;
const noOfRooms = 4;
const floorValue = Math.floor(usersCount/noOfRooms);
const ceilValue = Math.ceil(usersCount/noOfRooms);
console.log(`${floorValue} - ${ceilValue}  users per room`);

// Your try
for(let i = 1; i <= noOfRooms; i++) {
  if(i != noOfRooms) {
      console.log(floorValue); //push respective users based on this log length in order
  } else {
      console.log(ceilValue); //push respective users based on this log length in order
  }
}  

// Previous try
// function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
//     // console.log('CHeck ChunkSize', chunk_size);
//     var index = 0;
//     var arrayLength = myArray.length;
//     var tempArray = [];
//     for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
//         myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
//         // Do something if you want with the group
//         tempArray.push(myChunk);
//     }
//     return tempArray;
// }

// const usersCount = users.length;
// const noOfRooms = 4;
// const floorValue = Math.floor(usersCount/noOfRooms);
// const ceilValue = Math.ceil(usersCount/noOfRooms);
// // console.log(`${floorValue} - ${ceilValue}  users per room`);

// let borArr= [];

// for(let i = 1; i <= noOfRooms; i++) {
//   if(i != noOfRooms) {
//       const result =  chunkArray(users, floorValue);
//       const rec = {id: i, title: `${'Breakout room'}${i}`, users: result[i-1]};
//       borArr.push(rec);
//       // console.log(floorValue);
//   } else {
//       const result =  chunkArray(users, ceilValue);
//       const rec = {id: i, title: `${'Breakout room'}${i}`, users: result[i-2]};
//       borArr.push(rec);
//       // console.log(ceilValue);
//   }
// }

// console.log('CHeck***** arr', JSON.stringify(borArr));
```

```
Expected Output :

[{'id':1,'title':'Breakout room1','users':[{'id':1,'user':'User 1'},{'id':2,'user':'User 2'}]},{'id':2,'title':'Breakout room2','users':[{'id':3,'user':'User 3'},{'id':4,'user':'User 4'}]},{'id':3,'title':'Breakout room3','users':[{'id':5,'user':'User 5'},{'id':6,'user':'User 6'}]},{'id':4,'title':'Breakout room4','users':[{'id':7,'user':'User 7'},{'id':8,'user':'User 8'},{'id':9,'user':'User 9'}]}]
```

Comment: you can do snippets here in SO when you ask a question

Comment: Please share a [mcve] here instead of sending us to an external link

Comment: Where did `user 10` go in your expected output?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for that minimal reproducible demo & out of snippets. Updated question. Thank you @Alex

Comment: @Jamiec.. sorry for that.. updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That absolute easiest way would be to just round-robin allocate users to rooms. It does not give the exact output you said you wanted but has the same end goal of evenly distributing users to rooms as much as possible:

```
var rooms = [
  {id:1, name:"Room1",users:[]},
  {id:2, name:"Room2",users:[]},
  {id:3, name:"Room3",users:[]},
  {id:4, name:"Room4",users:[]},
]

for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
  rooms[i%rooms.length].users.push(users[i]);
}
```

```js
var users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        user: 'User 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        user: 'User 2'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        user: 'User 3'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        user: 'User 4'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        user: 'User 5'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        user: 'User 6'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        user: 'User 7'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        user: 'User 8'
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        user: 'User 9'
    }
]

var rooms = [
  {id:1, name:"Room1",users:[]},
  {id:2, name:"Room2",users:[]},
  {id:3, name:"Room3",users:[]},
  {id:4, name:"Room4",users:[]},
]

for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) {
  rooms[i%rooms.length].users.push(users[i]);
}

console.log(rooms);
```

Comment: thanks for Your quick reply.. If You run my code snippet the logs will print 2,2,2,3 in that order, I should have to push users in that order only